# How can i redirect console output in real-time on PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, console, ob-start

How can i redirect console output in real-time on PHP?

When i use ob_start() function, it stores outputs in buffer,
and calling ob_end_flush() the stored outputs are out.

But.. i want to redirect outputs in real-time..

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) without any output buffering.